# how can i reduce bandwidth usage when making hhtp/https requests to a website

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, https, request

I am running a small personal python service that uses a paid rotating proxy with limited bandwidth to make requests to websites and scrapes data from websites that have no api.

My question is now how can I reduce the bandwidth that is used when scraping websites? Can i somehow only get pure text or something like that?

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to add [HTTP compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) by adding `content-encoding: gzip` header to you requests. If proxy and target website are supporting this, then you should be able to reduce the bandwidth. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38866506/779084) on how to add such header in requests library.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately does this not work with the website I am scraping from (pastebin.com) as it does not support HTTP compression. At least i did not got it to work