# Is ViewState Compresssion worth it with ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, webforms

Obviously, first priority is disabling and not using Viewstate as much as possible, but if you have to, is this worthwhile?  Also considering that IIS is gzipping everything for you as well.  ViewState is smaller however is the trade off of CPU worth it?

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=67

Trying to give a client some guidance based on this.

PS:  They are using .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0):

If IIS is already gzipping everything (specifically relevant here is the HTML document itself), then you won't gain anything by compressing it yet again with the CustomPage implementation you linked to. It would be like zipping a zip.

Comment: This was my thought, if IIS was already gzipping, it seems like by overriding and compressing/decompressing ViewState, you are just adding extra CPU time for a task already taken care of at the IIS level.

Comment: It looks like HTTP level compression does not compress postbacks, only the main page, so maybe there is still a place for VS Compression:  http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/ramon/archive/2006/09/01/Don_2700_t-use-viewstate-compression_2100_-Use-http-compression-instead_2100_.aspx

Comment: @Shane, interesting, perhaps so after all

Comment: Here's a relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424917/why-cant-browser-send-gzip-request

Answer (score 0):

[Get view state off __VIEWSTATE](http://ajdotnet.wordpress.com/2007/03/17/get-view-state-off-__viewstate/)

*.... else get ready to be screwed!*

Comment: so is your blog post recommending to Compress ViewState or not bother?

Comment: @Shane There is always a stuck point with ViewState. I would say you should be concerned HOW-NOT to have or HOW-TO get alternate solution of this.