# How to make Compression Gzip in my xml request using asp code?

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I need to implement Compression Gzip in the below xml request

```
 <%

    pXML=Server.URLencode(XML_Request)    
set http = server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")    
http.open "post", "http://213.171.234.70/appservices/http/FrontendService", false

    http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type",
 "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"    
http.send  "xml_request=" &pXML

     http_response= http.responsexml.xml
     Set xd= Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
     xd.async = "false"
     xd.loadXML(http_response)

 %>
```

Please help to fix this.....

tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add the accept header, so the server will send gzip encoded content.

Add this to your code before `http.send`:

`http.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "compress, gzip"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot, HTTP protocol doesn't allow it. Please look here for more detailed explanation.
[Why can't browser send gzip request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424917/why-cant-browser-send-gzip-request)

Comment: any other method equilent to gzip to compress xml request