# Gzip ajax data before sending to server

Tags: javascript, json, gzip

I want to compress json data before sending to server. Is it possible without use of compressing libraries? Or which library should I use? Do I need to change anything on server side?

I'm using nginx, Rails on server side, jQuery on client side. Nginx already has been configured to compress json responses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't browser send gzip request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424917/why-cant-browser-send-gzip-request)

Comment: Thank you for this link. I see that subj is impossible without libraries. But the question about libraries still remain.