# gzip AngularJS Web request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, gzip

I am currently developing an application for mobile devices made in ANGULAR.js. This works with requests $http, uploading files .json more than 16000 records, and weighing more than 10mb. I want to know a way to compress the json file or something so not much despite my application. I need ideas for my application performance. if I can recommend examples would be very grateful.I am new in Angular.js.

I'm not sure if gzip is a good solution. if it could give me an example where you can see how the request is made to a Web service and how it can help to compress information.

Comment: Yes, gzip is perfect. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702124/enable-iis7-gzip

Comment: @MaxSorin I need a practical example in which you can make an example for angular.js

Comment: The client takes the gzip header supplied by the server and knows how to decode the content. Angular does not see or care that the content of the response was zipped.

Comment: Look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251856/compress-requests-from-angular-to-web-api for uploading files from the app.

Comment: @MaxSorin It is difficult, and I need something similar but in AngularJS