# How does server know to return gzipped data?

Tags: http, gzip

In the header exchange below I see that the server is returning the page Gzipped but I don't see where my browser ever indicated that it could accept GZip. How did the server know?

[image: Gzip headers]

Comment: [Here the answer was](http://stackoverflow.com/a/424948/1566267): "To compress the request the client would have to have a "pre-request" that actually negotiated that the request would be made compressed OR it would have to require compression as a supported encoding for ALL requests." Maybe some other request was done by the client?

Answer (score 0):

The content you have reproduced here is not what was sent by your browser; the "general" part is a mix of some of the request data and some of the response data. If you want to see the actual request an response, use something like wireshark.

Coincidentally, it is worth noting that some so-called security products will interfere with your browsers request - a common "enhancement" is to remove or mangle the header asking for compression. Your webserver will honour such requests in the absence of specific configuration to force compression. Google delivers a compressed JavaScript to the client when it sees such behaviour - if it runs on the client then Google start sending compressed content. There are Apache config snippets on the web which can detect and override some such tampering.

But there's no evidence here to suggest that is the case with your setup. You're just not seeing the request headers.